# What are some good practices to insert properties for class and methods to a class?

Tags: php, class, oop, properties, dependency-injection

Ok, the problem is that I am using a class, which depends on external configuration to work and validate things
but, since these properties are so many in quantity, I would like to know, how to import them.

So, imagine this is the class:

```
   class doSomething{

        public function __construct($conn){
            $this->conn = $conn;
        }

        public function validateURL($url){
            //do something with $url
        }

        public function validateName($name){
            //do something with $name
        }

        public function validateAge($age){
            // process age
        }

        public function lookEmailInDatabase($email, $table){
            // process data
        }

   }
```

Now, lets assume the above is inside a files called `doSomthingClass.php`

So, lets asume, that I have another class to declare values for those properties

```
function declareProperties($val){

    $conn = new PDO(...);
    $url = 'http://foo.com';
    $name = 'john';
    $age = '17';
    $email = 'simon@yahoo.com';
    $table = 'foobartar';

    return $val;


}
```

Now, the question is, what would be very efficient, **best way to export those properties into this class,** as I am not even sure, if the settings should be written inside a function, or another class ..

Comment: If the parameters are class-wide then they belong in the constructor. If they are call-specific (eg an Id) then they belong on the function itself. If you object to the number of parameters, make it one parameter which is a complex object containing all the properies needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`:

```
public $vars = array();

public function __get( $key )
{
    if( isset( $this->vars[$key] ) )
    {
        return $this->vars[$key];
    {
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function __set( $key, $value )
{
    $this->vars[$key] = $value;
}
```

And for an example: let's say $row is the data. If you use column names as property names (which is also good practice if you planned your structure well) you might make a method like this:

```
public function load( $row )
{
    if( is_array( $row ) )
    {
        foreach( $row as $key => $value )
        {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edit:**

You don't necessarily even have to pass in the variables like this, you can use the public methods externally:

```
$foo = new foo( $db );

$foo->bar( $three, $external, $params );
```

Does this work for your application?

Comment: But, the question was how to export them, and how to import them? Not, how to use them inside the class! I mean, do you create a separate file for them or what?

Comment: That's what the `load()` function is for. It's up to you how you want to use it, you can pull the data in from the constructor and pass it off like `$this->load( $row );` or from an outside class that gets the data (as an associative array) and do `$foo->load( $bar->data );`.

Comment: I don't understand, so you are telling me I should pass all properties through the constructor?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I thought you were just trying to pass them into the object. You don't even have to do that.

Comment: Imagine, this. I created a class that depends on some things to work, it is upto the user to export those properties, but the user must never change a single line from the class, all the settings and values are coming from other classes, but how do you inject those properties once, and never have to modify the class again?

Comment: This is called [Property Overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). It's either this or explicitly declaring the properties.

Comment: Well, I hoped for better example than a link to PO. but, I don't see any other so ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to constructor injection is setter or property injection.

It's not as "clean" as constructor injection because nothing guarantees you that the caller will indeed inject the dependencies.

```
class Example {
    private $property1;
    // Property injection (note that the property is public)
    public $property2;
    private $property3;

    public function __construct($param) {
        // Constructor injection
        $this->property1 = $param;
    }

    public function setProperty3($param) {
        // Setter injection
        $this->property3 = $param;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Constructor injection
$o = new Example($dependency1);

// Property injection
$o->property2 = $dependency2;

// Sett injection
$o->setProperty3($dependency3);
```

Now, you can also get help from a Container to automatically inject dependencies in properties or setters.

I usually get a lot of dependencies in controllers, so that's where I'll use property/setter injection. You can see [in this article](http://mnapoli.fr/controllers-as-services/) how I use my container for this.

Comment: Well, you made a better point, and I was almost tempted to mark your answer as accepted, but the one problem is that, if let's say you had about 8-9 properties to inject, your usage would make it seem a verbose code to write set all those properties, after instanting, so I have been thinking, what can be done to make those properties compact and well organized, so that injecting/setting them will not take more than one line of code? Lets just say, that I have to create a separate file to write the external properties once, but then how would you inject them

Comment: OK, if each method of your class wants different dependencies, then keep the code you showed in your question: don't inject 10 dependencies that's a lot. However, if each method gets the same 3 dependencies each time, then you end up injecting only 4 dependencies in the constructor (or setter injection). On a separate note, keep also in mind that you can use Property Injection, which is less verbose.

Comment: And finally, if your class has 10 dependencies, that's sometimes a sign that the class does too much, maybe you should split it in several smaller services.

Comment: Thanks, but I have cleared the question, if you are interested you could take a final look? thanks